# labelWithString is deprecated + glvertexPointer is invalid in c99

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to get rid of the warnings in my code and I'm stuck on these 2. 
For this part of my code i get `labelWithString:dimensions:alignment:fontName` is deprecated

```
CCLabelTTF *label1 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(count+1)] dimensions:CGSizeMake(30,40) alignment:UITextAlignmentRight fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:14];
```

And in another section of code when i call this function:

```
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
```

I get implicit declaration of function 'glVertexPointer' is invalid in c99.

Can anyone help?

This is my code containing glVertexPointer so far:
    ccDrawColor4F(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.2f);

```
float w = 320.0f;
float h = 27.0f;
float x = (320.0f - w) / 2.0f;
float y = 359.0f - currentScorePosition * h;

GLfloat vertices[4][2];
GLubyte indices[4] = { 0, 1, 3, 2 };

vertices[0][0] = x;     vertices[0][1] = y;
vertices[1][0] = x+w;   vertices[1][1] = y;
vertices[2][0] = x+w;   vertices[2][1] = y+h;
vertices[3][0] = x;     vertices[3][1] = y+h;


ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position );
kmGLPushMatrix();

glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);
kmGLPopMatrix();


ccDrawColor4F(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Answer (score 2):

For people who still haven't figured out how to get rid of `CCLabelTFF` being deprecated, use this instead:

```
CCLabelTTF *label1 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(count+1)] fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:14 dimensions:CGSizeMake(30,40) hAlignment:kCCTextAlignmentRight];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is i Putted method of `CCLabelTTF`

```
initWithString:dimensions:alignment:lineBreakMode:fontName:fontSize
```

Above method use instand of

```
+ labelWithString:dimensions:alignment:fontName:fontSize:
```

Method, It might be helpful in your case.

For More Information [read this official documentation](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/1.0/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_label_t_t_f.html)

> **I get implicit declaration of function 'glVertexPointer' is invalid in c99.**

This warning said that you define your method as a instance method, not like a function.

So, use `glVertexAttribPointer` instad of  `glVertexPointer`.

Comment: Cheers for that. I'm having abit of trouble using glVertexAttribPointer instead of glVertexPointer because they have a different number of arguments. I'm very new to cocos2d so I'm abit stuck. I'll put my code up so far

Comment: Im having the same issue...pls help

Comment: @marciokoko- please put your Question in stack overflow with fully details ..sure i will help you :) thanks :)